Scripts directory not installed
I am creating a smart contract where I have to run the script directory. But even after installing all the dependencies the directory is not getting added to the root folder.

Just add it manually ?
We would need more information to be able to help you.
What deployment framework are you using, which package manager ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
